# Is 1554 congruent to 9109 modulo 10663?

Tags: number-theory

I'm working out a number theory problem where I have to find the square root of 9109 modulo 10663.

The answer I get is 3502 but when I square this it is congruent to 1554 modulo 10663.

I notice that 1554 + 9109 = 10663

But this means that 1554 is congruent to -9109 not 9109.

I am not sure how to make sense of my result. Any ideas?

Comment: 10663 is one less than a multiple of 4.  So 9109 and -9109 can't both be squares mod 10663.  There won't be any solution.

Answer (score 1):

By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) ($9109, 10663$ are both prime; $9109\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $9109\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, $9109\equiv 1\pmod{12}$, $7\equiv -1\pmod{8}$, $37\equiv 1\pmod{4}$):

$$\left(\frac{9109}{10663}\right)=\left(\frac{10663}{9109}\right)=\left(\frac{1554}{9109}\right)$$

$$=\underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{9109}\right)}_{-1}\underbrace{\left(\frac{3}{9109}\right)}_{1}\left(\frac{7}{9109}\right)\left(\frac{37}{9109}\right)$$

$$=-\left(\frac{9109}{7}\right)\left(\frac{9109}{37}\right)=-\underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)}_{1}\left(\frac{7}{37}\right)$$

$$=-\left(\frac{37}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)=-1$$

Therefore $9109$ has no square root mod $10663$.

Also, of course $1554\not\equiv 9109\pmod{10663}$, because $1554$ leaves remainder $1554$ and $9109$ leaves remainder $9109$ when divided by $10663$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.